# How to load data in table view with specific height

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a table view in my application. In this i'm loading my data. I want that if the data load in first cell its height should be 120 and remaining cell should have height 50. I have also condition in didSelect delegate that if user select the cell , the current cell height increases to 120 and remaining cells have height 50 . How can i show my first cell height 120 and remaining with 50 . This is my code for when table view loads the data.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dishNameArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (flag == true && indexPath.row == indexValue) {
        return 120
    }
    else {

        return 40
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartTVC

    cell.dishNameLbl.text = dishNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.eachPriceLbl.text = priceArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.quantityLbl.text = "1"
    cell.qtyLbl.text = "1"
    cell.totalPriceLbl.text = priceArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.deleteBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crossBtnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}

@objc func crossBtnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    dishNameArray.remove(at: sender.tag)

    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = cartTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CartTVC
    print(cell)
    cartTableView.reloadData()
    print(sender.tag)
    print("II:\(dishNameArray.count)")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Yes")
    indexValue = indexPath.row
    if flag && indexValue == indexPath.row{
        // rfpNumberTableView.beginUpdates()
        let cell = self.cartTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CartTVC
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)

        self.cartTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
        // cartTableView.endUpdates()
        flag = false
    }
    else{

        let cell = self.cartTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CartTVC
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529120326, green: 0.3879342079, blue: 0.09117665142, alpha: 1)
        // rfpNumberTableView.beginUpdates()
        self.cartTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
        // cartTableView.endUpdates()
        flag = true
    }
}
```

This is how i want my first cell when table view loads data ,
[image]

Comment: what is the current problem

Comment: problem is that when any data load in table view it loads with height 40 . I want that whenever data loads in table view its first cell should have height 120 and remaining should have 40. and on click of cell the height gonna increase to 120. @Sh_Khan

Comment: why use the flag

Comment: I have used flag for my condition in didselect delegate, whenever user click any cell that is with 40 height it changes to height 120. @Sh_Khan

Comment: How can i show my first cell with 120 height only and remaining with 40 height when data is added to the tableview. @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
var indexValue = 0
```

//

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   if indexPath.row == indexValue {

      return 120

   else {

        return 50
   } 
}
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartTVC

    if indexPath.row == indexValue {
          cell.bgView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)

    }
    else {
          cell.bgView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529120326, green: 0.3879342079, blue: 0.09117665142, alpha: 1)

    }


    cell.dishNameLbl.text = dishNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.eachPriceLbl.text = priceArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.quantityLbl.text = "1"
    cell.qtyLbl.text = "1"
    cell.totalPriceLbl.text = priceArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.deleteBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crossBtnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Yes")


    if indexValue != indexPath.row {

         let oldIndex = IndexPath(row: indexValue , section: 0) 
         indexValue = indexPath.row
         self.cartTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath,oldIndex], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)


    }


}
```

Comment: perfecto. Thats what i want. @Sh_Khan

Comment: i'm getting a crash if i delete any cell from the table view. this is the crash message 0500 GrabPOS[72954:2623545] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 2 from section 0 which only contains 2 rows before the update'
@Sh_Khan

Comment: before you delete from the table make sure you delete from the dataSource array

Comment: yup, i'm deleting it in my crossBtnTapped method u can check in my code in question. @Sh_Khan

Comment: this is my deleting code.  @objc func crossBtnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        dishNameArray.remove(at: sender.tag)
        
        let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = cartTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CartTVC
        print(cell)
        cartTableView.reloadData()
        print(sender.tag)
        print("II:\(dishNameArray.count)")
    }

Comment: where the crash points , i think accessing a cell whose index is deleted ?

Comment: when i add multiple data in table view and than delete any item from it at position after 2 to 3 cell than it crashes with that error. @Sh_Khan